# datetime.datetime.now() + 1

Tags: python, django

I would like to add 1 day with 3 hours + datetime.now.

```
mante = Employee()
mante.usercompany = idnamez
mante.knowledgelost = datetime.datetime.now()+1 day more 3 hours.
mante.seguemplelost = datetime.datetime.now()+1 
mante.put()
```

Someone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1, hours=3)
```